# WP How to move a button in another position by php function

Tags: php, html, wordpress

What is the best way to reposition the "Empty Cart" button on the checkout in Woocommerce. Ideally, in a non-destructive way that respects the JS on the page refreshing the table.

OP Cannot find correct documentation in native language

Original post:

> I apologize immediately for the question. For many it will be
>   nonsense, but for me who is a beginner no. I need to move the empty
>   cart button next to the add to cart button. Through Google Inspect I
>   manage in 1 second to position the button where I want, but I can't do
>   it then through PHP in Wordpress. Sorry also for my english.
>
> Thank you.

[image: screenshot of the button layout]

Comment: Can I get the code you are using? Any code at all?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for JS or CSS than for PHP